# How much money has Neon Genesis Evangelion made?

Tags: anime-history, neon-genesis-evangelion

[This article](https://www.cbr.com/highest-grossing-anime-franchises-ranked/) says *Neon Genesis Evangelion* has made over $16 billion, but no reliable source on the Internet exists that would be accepted by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_media_franchises) as a reliable source.

Are there any reliable sources showing how much money the *Evangelion* franchise has made?

Comment: No, and that's ignoring bootleggers profiting off of it with unlicensed merch. I'm not aware of a source that says how much the [Saturn game](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/a/box/1/7/8/20178_front.jpg) made. Or any of the other [over 20 video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_video_games) based on Evangelion, for that matter. Or the soundtracks. Nevermind the [razors](https://www.ebay.com/itm/144246881321?epid=20039212395), we don't even know how much [Evangelion themed GPUs](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/asus-rtx-3090-evangelion-gpu-pre-orders-open-at-dol